# embed version control within TIBCO BPM process

Tags: svn, controls, version, tibco, business-process-management

I am trying to build a file management system through TIBCO ActiveMatrix Business Studio. for the file management system I want to also have version control capabilities.

I am wondering if there is any way for me to embed existing Version Control systems (e.g. SVN) into my process? so such that I can programmatically invoke the SVN functionalities through my process?

Thanks!

Shen

Answer (score 0):

Directly no, you are not able to call SVN from AMX BPM process, however always you are able to use this pattern AMX BPM process > Java > SVN API.

[Here you have a link to](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/business-studio-bpm-edition/4.1.0/doc/html/GUID-E919D787-8923-4598-9779-58AEB1F7C579.html) AMX BPM documentation where you can find how to use Java in process.

PS: If you have a an option to use webservice, then is better to expose such functionality as service and later call it from AMX BPM process.